# Insert an ad or image after the last word of paragraph

Tags: php, word-wrap

Suppose I want to add an image or ad unit after 500 characters. The 500th character ends on the letter that's not the *ending* letter of that word. I've used something like this;

```
$string = $post['message']; // String to split
$limit = '500'; // Characters limit
if (strlen($string) > $limit)
{
    $string = wordwrap($string, $limit);
    $string = substr($string, 0, strpos($string, "\n"));
}
```

But it splits the string before the paragraph ends. Also the remaining text of paragraph doesn't show which is obviously wrong.

So I basically want to add an IMAGE_CODE after 500 characters of a string where the image code should be inserted after 500th character exactly where the *paragraph ends*.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not completely sure what the output you are trying to make should look like, but if you just want to insert something between the paragraphs, this should work.

```
$string = $post['message']; // String to split
$limit = 500; // Characters limit

if (strlen($string) > $limit)
{
    $string = wordwrap($string, $limit);
    $nl = strpos($string, "\n");
    $string = substr($string, 0, $nl) . "\nIMAGE_CODE" . substr($string, $nl);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I have understood this thoroughly. But following should add image after 500 characters. I did not test this but it should work.

```
$newstring = wordwrap($string, $limit, "<img src='http//image.url' />\n");
```